# How can I prevent my faucet from spinning?

Tags: kitchens, sink, kitchen-sink

this faucet needs to spin, but after using hot water, or rotating too far, the base begins to spin in place. sometimes this causes leaking issues the plumbing underneath the sink since it all spins down there as well.

i've tried applying plumbing grease but it's not obvious to me how to take the faucet entirely apart, so i've only applied it in the more easily reached spots.

i'm struggling to tighten the nut seen in the second picture here, the basin wrench i bought seemed to be too small for it. the "Rigid EZ Change Faucet Tool" i bought doesn't seem to fit it either.

[image: faucet that spins]

[image: a difficult to reach nut under sink]

Comment: I believe you are on the right track, Try taking the wrench back and ask for an appropriate size. Take this picture along to your favorite store they should be able to help. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: For the leaky faucet, it may be caused by excessive wearing of the "o-ring". You will notice it after removing the handle and cartridge. To release or tighten the nut below the sink, you need the "basin wrench", which can be get from the hardware stores.

Comment: Generally speaking if the wrench doesn't fit the nut in question, then you get a different size wrench.